# angular repeat order by not work on nested scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a html table where rows are a object and data is a property:

```
$scope.rows = [
    { row_id: 1,row_selected:false, data: { col_1: "a", col_2: "b", col_3: "c" } },
    { row_id: 2,row_selected:false, data: { col_1: "d", col_2: "e", col_3: "f" } },
    { row_id: 3,row_selected:false, data: { col_1: "g", col_2: "h", col_3: "i" } }
]
```

and in table:

```
   <table border="1">
     <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="col in cols | orderBy:'order':false">
         <a href ng-click='changeOrderBy(col)'>{{col.name}} [{{col.order}}]</a>
       </th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:data[orderBy]:reverse | filter:filter">
       <td ng-repeat="col in cols | orderBy:'order':false">
         {{row.data[col.field]}}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

I tried with orderBy:data[orderBy] and orderBy:'data[orderBy]'

changeOrderBy function:

```
    $scope.changeOrderBy = function(col){
      if($scope.orderBy == col.field){
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
      }
      $scope.orderBy = col.field;
    }
```

But it does not seem to me to order the rows, and I suppose it will be a similar solution to make the filter

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rallesaid/ee7bh5ab/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, add the prefix 'data.' before the field, To be as follows

```
orderBy = 'data.col_1'
```

js:

```
$scope.orderBy = null;
$scope.reverse = false;
$scope.changeOrderBy = function(col){
  var prefix = 'data.';
  if($scope.orderBy == prefix + col.field){
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
  }
  $scope.orderBy = prefix + col.field;
}
```

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:orderBy:reverse">
```

[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rallesaid/ee7bh5ab/15/)